# How to fill a column in a dataframe based on conditions from a dataframe with different length?

Tags: r

So I have two dataframes, the first one is like this, with the name of different species of marine fish (the same species are repeated throughout the dataframe with a total of 74610 entries), their respective BIN (sort of a serial number that is assigned to a species based on a clustering algorithm), and an empty column (grade) that I want to fill based on conditions from the second dataframe:

## dataframe1

```
         species               BIN        grade
1.  Tilapia guineensis |  BOLD:AAL5979  |  NA

2.     Tilapia zillii  |  BOLD:AAB9042  |  NA

3. Fundulus rubrifrons |  BOLD:AAI7245  |  NA

4.  Eutrigla gurnardus |  BOLD:AAC0262  |  NA

5.   Sprattus sprattus |  BOLD:AAE9187  |  NA

6.        Gadus morhua |  BOLD:ACF1143  |  NA
```

The second dataframe has the species (only repeated once this time, with a total of just 7633 entries) and the number of BINs that's assigned to each species:

## dataframe2

```
        species             bin_per_species       BIN
                                                                                            
1. Abalistes filamentosus |       1        |  BOLD:AAD4738
                                       
2. Abalistes stellaris    |       2        |  BOLD:AAD4739,BOLD:ACK7828 
                         
3. Abalistes stellatus    |       2        |  BOLD:AAD4739,BOLD:ACK7828 
                         
4. Ablabys binotatus      |       1        |  BOLD:AAF8834   
                                    
5. Ablennes hians         |       2        |  BOLD:AAC1231,BOLD:AAB9824

6. Abramis brama          |       1        |  BOLD:AAC8592
```

What I want to do is basically fill the grade column in dataframe1 considering the number of BINs that's assigned to each species in dataframe2. For example, if in dataframe2 a species has bin_per_species==1 I want to assign the grade "A", but if for instance a species in dataframe2 has a bin_per_species>1 I want to assign in the grade "C".

I have tried using the %in% function since I can't use "==" since they have different lengths.

## failed attempt

```
dataframe1$grade[(as.character(dataframe1$species)%in%as.character(dataframe2$species))[dataframe2$bin_per_species==1]]="A"
```

I would expect dataframe1 to be filled according to the condition but what happens is that it just fills every cell with the grade "A" when I try the code above.
I'm sorry if I was confusing in presenting my problem, but thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: There are completely different species with different BINs in your two example dataframes. Can you give us better sample data? Also, if BINs and/or species names are unique, the easiest thing to do would be to merge/join.

Comment: Yeah, those samples weren't the best example sorry...the thing is, in the dataframe1 each species is assigned to a BIN, but since there are several instances of the same species in dataframe1, some instances of the same species have completely different BINs. That's the reasoning behind assigning grades to each species

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your two dataframes aren't very helpful, but I think it's possible to work backwards from the second dataframe to arrive at more representative data. Based on your comment, the first dataframe can contain the same `species` with different `BIN`s. If that's the case then we can just pull apart the second dataframe to get `df1`:

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  species                BIN          grade
  <chr>                  <chr>        <int>
1 Abalistes filamentosus BOLD:AAD4738    NA
2 Abalistes stellaris    BOLD:AAD4739    NA
3 Abalistes stellatus    BOLD:AAD4739    NA
4 Ablabys binotatus      BOLD:AAF8834    NA
5 Ablennes hians         BOLD:AAC1231    NA
6 Abramis brama          BOLD:AAC8592    NA
7 Abalistes stellaris    BOLD:ACK7828    NA
8 Abalistes stellatus    BOLD:ACK7828    NA
9 Ablennes hians         BOLD:AAB9824    NA
```

The second dataframe `df2` remains the same.

#### Using one dataframe

If I've understood the problem correctly, you really don't even need the second dataframe. Instead, you could do something like this, which groups by `species` and and gives each group a grade based on its size `n()`:

```r
df1 %>% 
    group_by(species) %>% 
    mutate(grade = ifelse(n() == 1, "A", "C"))

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   species [6]
  species                BIN          grade
  <chr>                  <chr>        <chr>
1 Abalistes filamentosus BOLD:AAD4738 A    
2 Abalistes stellaris    BOLD:AAD4739 C    
3 Abalistes stellatus    BOLD:AAD4739 C    
4 Ablabys binotatus      BOLD:AAF8834 A    
5 Ablennes hians         BOLD:AAC1231 C    
6 Abramis brama          BOLD:AAC8592 A    
7 Abalistes stellaris    BOLD:ACK7828 C    
8 Abalistes stellatus    BOLD:ACK7828 C    
9 Ablennes hians         BOLD:AAB9824 C
```

#### Using two dataframes

If, for some reason, you need to use `df1` and `df2`, I think the most straightforward approach would be to join the two dataframes on `species`, and then mutate `grade` according to the values of `bin_per_species`:

```r
full_join(df1, df2, by = "species") %>% 
    mutate(grade = case_when(bin_per_species == 1 ~ "A",
                             bin_per_species == 2 ~ "B",
                             bin_per_species  > 2 ~ "C",
                             )) %>% 
    select(1:3)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  species                BIN.x        grade
  <chr>                  <chr>        <chr>
1 Abalistes filamentosus BOLD:AAD4738 A    
2 Abalistes stellaris    BOLD:AAD4739 B    
3 Abalistes stellatus    BOLD:AAD4739 B    
4 Ablabys binotatus      BOLD:AAF8834 A    
5 Ablennes hians         BOLD:AAC1231 B    
6 Abramis brama          BOLD:AAC8592 A    
7 Abalistes stellaris    BOLD:ACK7828 B    
8 Abalistes stellatus    BOLD:ACK7828 B    
9 Ablennes hians         BOLD:AAB9824 B
```

I included `case_when()` in case you have more than just the two grades "A" and "C". You can also use it in the "one dataframe" solution. If you really only have those two grades then you can simplify things with `ifelse()`:

```r
full_join(df1, df2, by = "species") %>% 
    mutate(grade = ifelse(bin_per_species == 1, "A", "C")) %>% 
    select(1:3)
```

Comment: thank you so much, you're right I don't even need the second one, it works perfectly with ifelse

Comment: @tadeufontes good to hear. Please consider upvoting the answer, and accepting it by clicking the ✓ to the left, so others know what worked for you.

Comment: oh ok, I still can't upvote because I have less than 15 reputation but I've just clicked the ✓, ty again

Answer (score 0):

welcome

Please check out if this works, and look into the dput() function.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~species,~BIN,
              "A",1,
              "B",2,
              "B",3,
              "B",4)

df %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise(count_bins = n()) %>% 
  mutate(grade = if_else(count_bins > 1,
                         "C",
                         "A")) %>% 
  right_join(df)
```

Comment: you only need df1

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your problem in order for me to test it, please notify me if this doesn't work for you. I left my simple dataframes in so you can se my process.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  species <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  grade <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
colnames(df1) <- c('species', 'grade')

df2 <- data.frame(
  species <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  bin_per_species <- c(1, 2, 2, 1)
)
colnames(df2) <- c('species', 'bin_per_species')

df1[species %in% df2[which(df2[, 'bin_per_species'] == 2), 'species'], 'grade'] <- 'A'
```